# knnimpute package in python

Tags: python, knn, imputation

I am trying to perform a knn imputation using the python package [knnimpute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/knnimpute). I am kind of lost with what the parameter missing_mask should be. I fail to understand what this means ( from the docs)

```
 missing_mask : np.ndarray
            Boolean array of same shape as X
```

Somebody who has used this package - would be great if you can help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

`missing_mask` should be `np.isnan(your_numpy_matrix_data)`.

In my environment it goes ok.